# Service worker does not load mp3 files

Tags: google-chrome, resources, twilio, service-worker

Trying to load an mp3 file from the following source:
https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/refs/82278dd/sounds/dtmf-1.mp3

Using very simple request redirecting code in service worker:

```
function onFetch(event) {
    if (event.request.url.indexOf('.mp3') >= 0) {
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request.url, {mode: 'no-cors'}));
    } else {
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }
}
```

have tried other options as well:

```
fetch(event.request)

fetch(event.request.url)

fetch(event.request.url, {mode: 'cors'})
```

note: no error thrown in service worker if I pass {mode: 'no-cors'}, error thrown for all other mentioned cases:

> Fetch API cannot load https://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/refs/82278dd/sounds/dtmf-1.mp3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'my origin' is therefore not allowed access.

I think the issue may be is that Service Worker does not send Accept-Encoding and Range Headers, so it does not load the resource.

Any kind of help, hacking would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/280 (The error returned by Chrome isn't particularly helpful here, but I believe that's the underlying issue.) You're going to want to avoid making any `Request` that relies on a `Range` headers, so constructing a new `Request` with the same target URL and an empty set of headers is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the response. I have added a proxy in nginx which "serves" those twilio files from my domain. Of course it required hack in their sdk code to change request location to my domain, which then redirects to the same url but with twilio domain. That worked for me. I was aware of the #280 issue on SW github account. I think the issue is kind of different server configuration at twilio that SWs are not designed to be clients of.